# Not enough space or text is aligned incorrectly in image upload?

Tags: bug, status-completed, image-upload

I have noticed that the text  *`to upload your image (max 2 MiB)`* is not getting enough space to fit in the image upload box. In short, you can say, it is not aligned correctly.

Here is an image:

[image: Showing the text is overlapping and outside the box's border.]

---

**Zoomed:**

> [image]

---

**Another zoomed image:**

> [image]

---

Is it a bug or not or is there a logic behind it? To me it seems to be a bug.

**Note: As this bug is reproduced on all Stack Exchange sites, I have asked it on Meta.SE: *[Not enough space or text is aligned incorrectly in Image upload?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317291/366626)***

Comment: We want our hand drawn circles! Don't deprive us like this.

Comment: [Repro'd](https://gyazo.com/73f8e82bb8fd37216557e89cdb482495): Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Script47 What do you mean by hand drawn circles?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/218388). Though, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to) might be better suited for you.

Comment: Does it look good now?

Comment: Well, I mean you can never have too many circles but this is a start I guess. :P