# Weird flickering effect when changing vote

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting

So, I mistakenly down-voted a question and noticed a weird flickering effect which caught my eye:

[image: red circle meme]

It seems related to the opacity during the animation.

**OS:** Windows 10

**Browser:** Chrome; 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I can't tell if people are testing it out on this question or just don't like my report...

Comment: Rough guess: the embedded javascript reduces it by 1, it doesn't know you already voted for it.  The web socket produces the real value after consulting the dbase.  The flicker rate tells you how far you live away from NY :)

Comment: Do you get that flicker with the digit-value on voting up again also? - If not you could change the title to "Weird flickering effect when changing vote (on downvote)" to be more precise..

Comment: @iLuvLogix I get it for both as can be seen in the image.

Comment: The downvotes are clearly because you didn't include [red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/235923) in your jiff.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I never thought the day would come where an [avid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377175/cant-re-flag-a-comment-after-the-answer-is-deleted-and-then-undeleted) [advocator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377215/tag-post-i-like/377216#377216) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375496/not-enough-space-or-text-is-aligned-incorrectly-in-image-upload#comment639370_375496) [circles](https://tinyurl.com/ydhkb5ru) like myself would get quoted the meme. I am out of my depth here, how can I add circles to GIF? :O

Comment: Adding free-hand circles to a GIF cannot be taught. It is a natural skill transcendence which separates the casuals from the gifted.

Comment: issue seen with Firefox too.

Comment: Apparently your vote gets locked in if you fiddle with it too much. I'm now locked into a downvote on this bug report.

Comment: Repro'd consistently in Firefox 63.0.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: Repro in Waterfox 56.2.5, Windows 7

Comment: Repro in Chromium Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus don't you mean GIFed? :p

Comment: The lottery yielded an upvote for you https://i.stack.imgur.com/NocZA.png

Comment: @YvetteColomb I had my chance and I blew it :-/

Comment: Repro in Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10

Comment: Repro in Safari 12.0.1 (latest) macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Comment: definitly a first-world problem

Comment: I can see people testing this live! :-D

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - there - fixed.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you for for gracing us casuals with your presence; we are not worthy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking closely at the GIF and even testing it on my Google Chrome the behavior appears to be actually counting through the middle number between the value of an upvote and downvote; and vice versa.

You are not seeing a random flicker but rather that the vote goes from 301, split-second at 300, and stop at 299. The same is true in reverse.

However, it seems to be about a 50/50 chance that the "flickering" occurs. Up/down voting your question sometimes causes the "flicker" and other times it just goes to the exact number without stopping in the middle.

Comment: ajax dice rolls ;)

Comment: May be right, but still very poor app behavior.

Answer (score 12):

The cause is:

The number is updated when any of the following occurs:

- Someone votes on the post and its score changed (event is received via a server broadcast, I guess it's websocket)
- You click to vote / unvote

This depends a lot on your network connectivity. To explain your GIF, the following (presumably) happened:

1. You click UP and the page immediately displays an incremented number (301)
2. The server broadcasts that the new score for the post is 301, which does not cause any visual change
3. You click DOWN and the page immediately displays a decremented number (299)
4. Your UP is cancelled and the server broadcast is received. The new score is 300
5. Your DOWN is applied *after* cancelling your UP, and the server broadcasts it again. The new score is 299.

Event **4** is the "flicker" that you see. If you're in a bad network environment, it can last longer than just a blink of an eye.

Comment: Thanks for digging into the root cause here. I have a fix waiting to be built out, and it'll go live with the next prod build.

Answer (score 5):

Just tested this on your question in chrome version 70.0.3538.110 and I get the behaviour described by MonkeyZeus on voting down.

When voting up again however, I just get the color to flicker a bit into lighter grey and then back to normal, but the digit itself doesn't flicker with a different value..

Comment: Repro on Waterfox 56.2.5